# Best way to make a ternary relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What is the best way to make a ternary relationship `laravel`?

I'm making an application "multi client/company" (basecamp type) and appeared the following relationship:

a `user` has many `(0 .. n) permissions` that organization, and users, permissions and organizations are entities.

basically the BD would have a table with the keys:

```
user_id
permission_id
organization_id
```

Now the problem is how to do it in laravel.

Comment: Can we see your attempts to implement the `hasMany` method

Comment: I still do not have any code, because hasMany method doesn't support two `foreign keys`

Comment: [Here you go, then](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: this not resolve/apply my problem. eager loading exists to alleviate the N + 1 query problem. not for ternary relationships

Comment: I am not following your desired relationship, so don't have an answer now.  First, can you include a diagram of your schema?  Second, food for thought: can you convert your 3-ary to 3x binary relationships?  (eg, ["When the single ternary relationship type has been replaced by three binary relationship types, each of the relationships and their inverses can be named."](http://www.databasedesign.co.uk/bookdatabasesafirstcourse/chap3/chap3.htm))

Comment: What relation exactly you need? Rephrase your question, it's unclear